# Can not find image using pyautogui

Tags: python, pyautogui

Using mac

```
import time
time.sleep(10.4)
a=pyautogui.locateOnScreen('/Users/husaynjaffer/Dropbox/Mac/Desktop/Screen Shot 2021-07-17 at 1.22.32 AM.png', grayscale=False, confidence =.5)
print(a)
```

returns None

expected: "location of the file on screen"

any ideas to debug or fix anyone with the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the image was not located on the screen, check out the [code](https://github.com/asweigart/pyscreeze/blob/0446e87235e0079f591f0c49ece7d487dedc2f9a/pyscreeze/__init__.py#L350). To debug it you have to step through the function and check where it goes wrong.